# How does the head of a garlic compare to its stem?

Tags: garlic

I'm shocked at how fast my garlic stems are growing (about 1 inch per day, and there has only been about 2 weeks of growing weather), so I was wondering how the size of the garlic bulb compares to the stem of the garlic.

If you're wondering how I picked it, I looked for the stuff they intended to throw out due to sprouting.

Comment: http://www.sustainablemarketfarming.com/tag/garlic-bulb-formation/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Studies show that the size of the final bulb is determined by the size of the clove that is planted. Larger cloves put out bigger leaves which results in greater photosynthesis and more energy for bulb production.

If you're serious about growing garlic, it's suggested that you buy local garlic seed aka bulbs as local varieties will be suitable for your local environment.  If you grow from sprouting bulbs in your local grocer's which have come from wherever, it is just not ideal but I guess you've lost little.

Comment: Actually the first head I planted is booming, and the next heads have yet to come up. They should be coming next week.

Comment: If you get large bulbs, you could just keep them to propagate next year instead of eating them.

Comment: I plan to until I get bowling ball sized heads of garlic.

Comment: Elephant garlic is a much larger form of garlic that is more related to onions.  So, you'll get size, but not taste.

Comment: I do want the taste also, so I won't be doing Elephant Garlic.